# Wlanapi.dll Entrypoint not found exception

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, wlanapi

When I try to invoke WlanOpenHandle method of wlanapi.dll, code throws EntryPointNotFoundException.

C#:

```
[DllImport("wlanapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint WlanOpenHandle([In] UInt32 clientVersion, [In, Out] IntPtr pReserved, [Out] out UInt32 negotiatedVersion, [Out] out IntPtr clientHandle);
```

---

C#:

```
uint dwClientVersion = 1;
IntPtr pReserved = IntPtr.Zero;
uint pdwNegotiatedVersion;
IntPtr phClientHandle;

var result = WlanOpenHandle(dwClientVersion, pReserved, out pdwNegotiatedVersion, out phClientHandle);
```

The [web site](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi.WlanOpenHandle) says that entry point exist. What is the missing part?

Comment: MSDN is the real reference, what does it say?

Comment: wlanapi.dll contains WlanOpenHandle function. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706759(v=vs.85).aspx)) but my pinvoke code does not work

Comment: Seems a bit odd. What OS and what type of app?

Comment: first part of code(dll import) used in **_standard class library_** and  second part used in **_.net framework 4.7.1 console app_**. OS version is windows 10 @DavidHeffernan